How to access a hash in another file?
Below is the content of P4site.pm:
 our %regVal = (
        'wint' => {
            'Bangalore' => {
                'regSuffix' => 'reg_run',
                'P4PORT' => {
                    'rd' => '9876',
                    'pv' => '1991',
                },
            },
            'Noida' => {  
                 'activeRelease' => {
                    'rd' => {
                             '43.1' => ['rc011', 'nfm'],
                             '98.3' => ['rc008', 'nfm'],
                             '57.3' => ['rc001', 'nfm'],
                     },
                    'pv' => {
                             '43.1' => ['rc011', 'nfm'],
                             '98.3' => ['rc008', 'nfm'],
                             '57.3' => ['rc001', 'nfm'],
                     }
                }

My perl code is:
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/modules";
use P4site;
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper(\%{$P4site::regVal});

foreach my $branches (sort keys %{$P4site::{regVal}})
{
    print "$branches is bracnhes\n";
}

Why is sort keys %{$P4site::{regVal}} not giving any output?
Output of the perl code is:
Name "P4site::regVal" used only once: possible typo at allUtilsCopyUserRunMach.pl line 14.
$VAR1 = {};

I was expecting that the keys of regVal hash (mentioned in P4site) would be printed after running this Perl code? How can I print the keys of the regVal hash?

Rolled back your edits. Don't edit the Question to remove the error you're asking about. (Some unrelated edits got caught in the crossfire. Feel free to reapply them.) Re-added some

The problem is that you're missing
package P4site;

in your module. Your code works with this addition.

While valid, note that %{$P4site::{regVal}} is really weird way of achieving what you want. You're accessing the variable indirectly through a glob of the symbol table. If you don't know what that means, that goes to show how weird it is. You should be using %P4site::regVal instead.

As for your second question,
%{ $P4site::regVal{wint}{Noida}{activeRelease} }

and
$P4site::regVal{wint}{Noida}{activeRelease}->%*

are two ways of getting the hash you want. You can provide these to keys.

Other improvements:

You should use $RealBin (from FindBin) instead of $Bin to avoid problems with symlinks

